# How secured is laravel S3 temporary URL?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, amazon-s3

I would like to know if providing temporary url to access AWS bucket objects are secured in a sense that it discloses the AWS Access Key.

From my knowing if using IAM user's access key for accessing AWS bucket rather than root Access key can be highly secured if the IAM user is only permitted to read/write S3 services.

Are there any disadvantages of providing temporary url to the public using IAM user's access key?

Regards.

Comment: AWS access keys are public. The secrets are not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presigning a URL doesn't give away your private key (secret), so there is no risk. An attacker couldn't take a signed URL and alter it to do something else, as the signature verifies the original payload.

You are correct: it's considered good practice to lock down IAM profiles to specific tasks, such as a specific application environment.

According to the [official AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_root-user.html):

> We strongly recommend that you do not use the root user for your
>   everyday tasks, even the administrative ones. Instead, adhere to the
>   best practice of using the root user only to create your first IAM
>   user. Then securely lock away the root user credentials and use them
>   to perform only a few account and service management tasks.

---

Your disadvantages question isn't clear to me, so I'll answer two ways I think you might have meant it:

- **Tailored IAM profiles** over **root:**

  No disadvantage. Requires a bit more time and awareness to plan your policy / permission requirements, but that's a good thing.
- **Pre-signed URLs** over **conventional uploads / downloads**

  This depends on your use-case. Generally speaking, there are no extra security considerations when using presigned URLs. Just set a realistic expire time and don't give it to the wrong person. It's a lot like a session / bearer token that way.

  In terms of advantages, they open up doors to make your application more scalable, and removes the need for your application to waste cycles "watching" an authorized upload or download. Vapor (Laravel 6 on Lambda) promotes presigned URLs as a feature for file uploads.

Comment: Cheers. I hope it helps others too.